# Is there a way to implement an Outlook add-in which always runs in background?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am implementing an Outlook add-in which tracks emails on a personal web app.
Currently it just allows the user to select and track a single email.
I would like to extend it to manage the whole thread.
I mean: I would like it to periodically scan new items inside the mailbox to automatically track the potential responses.
Actually, a kind of "on-receive" trigger would be nicer, but I have not found anything about looking at the "Event-based Outlook add-in" docs.

Hoping the question is not too trivial, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item only. So, you need to select an item to trigger an add-in. There is no  "on-receive" trigger unfortunately.

Note, feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

As a possible workaround you may take a look at [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Comment: Hi, could you explain more on how Graph API may help the use case in this question please?

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in new threads, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.